# How to generate running total of a column based on other columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a df which has two columns `bear_start_count` and `td_sell_setup`. 
Using these two columns, I need to workout another column `td_sell_count`.

The conditions for `td_sell_count` are as follows:

When `bear_start_count` == 1 & `td_sell_setup` == 0, then `td_sell_count` == 1

thereafter, when `bear_start_count` == 0 and `td_sell_setup` == 1; `td_sell_count` = the prior row `td_sell_count` + the current row `td_sell_setup` value

the `td_sell_count` resets to 0 when both `bear_start_count` and `td_sell_setup` == 0

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
         bear_start_count = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                              0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                              0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            td_sell_setup = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
                              0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                              1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
            td_sell_count = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0,
                              0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
                              15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
      )
```

The df above gives both the existing columns asl well as the calculated column.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create a grouping variable with `rleid` based on 'bear_start_count', 'td_sell_setup' columns, and then check `if` the `paste`d values "10", "01" are in the group, then get the `row_number()` or `else` return 0 (implemented with `case_when`)

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
out <- df %>% 
       mutate(newcol = str_c(bear_start_count, td_sell_setup)) %>% 
       group_by(grp = rleid(newcol %in% c("10", "01"))) %>% 
       mutate(td_sell_count1 =  case_when(all(c("10", "01") %in% newcol)
                     ~ row_number(), TRUE ~ 0L)) %>%
       ungroup %>%
       select(-grp, -newcol)
```

-checking with OP's expected output

```
all.equal(out$td_sell_count, out$td_sell_count1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: thanks, really elegant solution to a complex situation!